# Best strategy for querying large MySQL table with Powershell and storing in a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, powershell, database-performance

I'm trying to figure out the best strategy (optimized for memory consumption) for storing a result set from MySQL in a Powershell variable.

The reason I ask is because I have a semi-large table (30 million rows, 4 columns) that take up 2GB on disk and yet consumes 8GB in memory when stored in a variable of type: [System.Collections.ArrayList]

Basically, I'm doing this:

```
$devTable = sql_datareader -query $query
```

It's a bit slow-ish (10 mins) to complete....I can live with that (sort of). But, its the memory consumption that is bothering me. I know I can make multiple queries, iterate over the results, and then clear the array. But, ideally, I'd like to avoid multiple queries.

Anyone have any ideas on how to keep the memory pressure down?

Thanks!

Comment: Closing question as there is no way to accomplish the goal and keep memory consumption low.

Answer (score 0):

Closing question as there is no way to accomplish the goal and keep memory consumption low.